# Yaws server started on localhost of Azure but not accessed from cloudapp.net

Tags: azure, erlang, httpserver, yaws

I started the Yaws server on Windows Azure VM successfully, but I cannot access the public domain.

For now, I just want to use Yaws to host my static contents.

I searched some articles but haven't found a solution.

Here is detail, and please give me some idea, thanks.

### I started the Yaws server on localhost:8000

I have started Yaws server by following conf:

```
# /etc/yaws/conf.d/localhost.conf

<server localhost>
    port = 8000
    listen = 127.0.0.1
    docroot = /home/me/website
    # dir_listings = true
</server>
```

I think I started http server successfully, because I can `curl` the content of `index.html` by :

```
curl losthost:8000
```

### I bind the endpoint in Windows Azure VM

And I also set up the endpoint on Window Azure VM (Ubuntu Server 15.04):

```
NAME | PROTOCOL | PUBLIC PORT | PRIVATE PORT
:----|:---------|:------------|:-------------
HTTP | TCP      | 80          | 8000
```

### But cannot access `azeure_vm_name.cloudapp.net`

But I cannot access the static web site by `azure_vm_name.cloudapp.net`.

`cloudapp.net` is the public domain of Windows Azure VM.

### But I can access public domain starting python server

Before, I tried start python http.server in folder `/home/me/website`:

```
# python 3
python -m http.server
# python 2
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

### INFO REPORT from Yaws server

```
$ sudo yaws -i
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-
poll:true]

Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
1>
=INFO REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::07:30:46 ===
Yaws: Using config file /etc/yaws/yaws.conf

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::07:30:46 ===
Yaws: Using subconfig file /etc/yaws/conf.d/localhost.conf

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::07:30:48 ===
yaws debug:Add path "/usr/lib/yaws/custom/ebin"

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::07:30:48 ===
yaws debug:Add path "/usr/lib/yaws/examples/ebin"

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::07:30:48 ===
yaws debug:Running with id="default" (localinstall=false)
Running with debug checks turned on (slower server)
Logging to directory "/var/log/yaws"

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::07:30:48 ===
Ctlfile : /home/me/.yaws/yaws/default/CTL

=INFO REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::07:30:48 ===
Yaws: Listening to 127.0.0.1:8000 for <1> virtual servers:
 - http://localhost:8000 under /home/me/website
```

### References

[Installing Yaws server on Ubuntu 12.04 (Using a cloud service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449114/installing-yaws-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-using-a-cloud-service)

https://askubuntu.com/q/190841/249957

Comment: I suspect Yaws is dropping your requests because the server name in your requests doesn't match any of its configured servers. Check the logs under `/var/log/yaws` to see if they show any errors. You might also consider running `sudo yaws -i --debug` which might give you more information.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and test, I found a solution finally.

#### final solution

Here is the final `yaws.conf`:

```
<server azure_VM_name.cloudapp.net>
    port = 8000
    listen = <Azure VM INTERNAL IP ADDRESS>
    docroot = /home/scotv/repo/shanlin-web
    # dir_listings = true
</server>
```

#### how to find this solution

Thanks to @steve-vinoski 's advice, I open the `--debug` switch, and read the official documents "Yaws - Yet Another Web Server (Oct 7, 2015 version)".

On page 9, `Yaws` PDF document mentions:

> The configuration in Example 2.1 defined one HTTP server on address 127.0.0.1:8000 called "localhost".
>   It is important to understand the difference between the name and the address of a server. **The name is the
>   expected value in the client HTTP Host: header**. That is typically the same as the fully-qualified **DNS name**
>   of the server whereas **the address is the actual IP address of the server.**

So I checked the HTTP Request Header in browser:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: azure_VM_name.cloudapp.net
Connection: keep-alive
```

That is why I changed the `yaws.conf` to :

```
# <server localhost> </server>
<server azure_VM_name.cloudapp.net> </server>
```

The next step is find out which IP I need listen to, according to message from `SimpleHTTPServer`:

```
python -m SmpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

I decided to listen to `0.0.0.0`

And it works, I can access to azure_VM_name.cloudapp.net now.

However, the manual of `yaws.conf` mentions:

> SERVER PART
>
> listen = IpAddress
>
> If the specified IP address is 0.0.0.0 Yaws will listen on **all local IP addresses** on the specified port.

I dont want to listen on all.

So I checked the IP addresses provided from Windows Azure VM, we have:

```
DNS NAME
azrue_VM_name.cloudapp.net
HOST NAME
azrue_VM_name
PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS
40.*.*.*
INTERNAL IP ADDRESS
100.*.*.*
```

I tried PUBLIC VIP and INTERNAL IP, finally I found that I should listen on INTERNAL IP:8000.

So now, I am running the `yaws`:

```
sudo yaws -D --heart --debug --conf ./deploy/yaws.conf
```

Comment: If you're now happy with the way it's running, you can turn off `--debug`.